# Uploading file on change of file input

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to upload a file on change of file input but I can't get it to work because I am not so good with javascript.

I did search on google and found this: [How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery)

I used it and tried to change it to how I want to use it. But I am getting the error

```
`Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`
```

This is my function:

```
function uploadFile(formData){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'inc/ajax/uploadFile.php',  //Server script to process data
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'formData':formData},
        //Ajax events
        success: function(html){
            alert(html);
        }
    });
}
```

I call the function like this:

```
$("input:file").change(function(){
    var file = this.files[0];
    uploadFile(file);
})
```

And uploadFile.php

```
<?php
 $formData = $_GET['formData'];
 echo $formData;
?>
```

I am just testing and trying to return the file in php to see if I can get it to work. But I have no idea on how I have to call it in PHP or send it with AJAX. I know how to upload it with PHP once I can retrieve the $_FILES in PHP.

Comment: $_GET on the client & on the server $_POST?

Comment: `$_GET['formData'];` should be empty since you're sending a POST request...

Comment: Note, uploading files like this will NOT work in IE<9, or is it 10?

Comment: Sorry I changed it to POST instead. But am I supposed to call formData like I do? And thanks Kevin B I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the other answer, add this to your ajax

```
contentType: false,
processData: false
```

like:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('formData', file);
$.ajax({
    url: 'inc/ajax/uploadFile.php',  //Server script to process data
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    //Ajax events
    success: function(html){
        alert(html);
    }
});
```

You should also think about people that may not have a newer browser, and just put a little error message, like:

```
if(window.FormData === undefined){
    alert('sorry buddy, your browser\'s too old!');
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you this fixed the error. But how do I have to call it in PHP? $_POST['formData'] doesn't work.

Comment: @Xegano, depending on what you named your form elements. do a `var_dump($_POST);` and `var_dump($_FILES);` - that will show you what data is being sent to the server.

Comment: Thanks! I had to call "$_FILES['formData']" and it returned the array.

Answer (score 2):

You need to sent the data as a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object

```
function uploadFile(file){
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('formData', file);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'inc/ajax/uploadFile.php',  //Server script to process data
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        //Ajax events
        success: function(html){
            alert(html);
        }
    });
}
```

http://blog.new-bamboo.co.uk/2012/01/10/ridiculously-simple-ajax-uploads-with-formdata

Comment: Thanks a lot this makes sense. But I am still getting the same error.. And the error comes from the line "data: formData,"